# CSS not applying to my div

Tags: html, css

I have a div that I really need to apply my css attributes to. The page is structured like this:

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
         <div class="newFormRightContent">
```

I have a .form-group in my stylesheet and that comes out fine on the page, but my .newFormRightContent styles never get assigned. I am using chrome inspect element and can see that at newFormRightContent level, the styles are inherited from form-group and from the user-agent ss.

I have tried various combo's of selectors in my css:

```
div.form-group.newFormRightContent {

.form-group.newFormRightContent {

.newFormRightContent {
```

None seem to work - can someone please educate me on my failings here please!!

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to leave space between .form-group and .newFormRightContent

```
.form-group .newFormRightContent{
```

and try to set your styles `!important`

Comment: Correct answer, except for the `!important`. That one really spoils the answer.

Comment: @arkascha in the question he tried to use this only `.newFormRightContent` and his style didn't applied

Comment: Whilst that is true (I can read), still using `!important` typically is a very bad idea. It can cause a bunch of other issues and it is simply ugly. I would suggest to solve the problem why those rules do not catch instead, won't you agree?

Comment: @arkascha I think it may override by other css or using js so set it !important

Comment: Sorry, but programming is not a guessing game. There are reasons and the solution is to find them. Then you can solve them. What you are doing is wild guessing. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.form-horizontal > .form-group > .newFormRightContent
```

This will make sure only nested situation gets the design and no other situations get modified. Not using the child `>` selector will result in unnecessary design override in some other places where the given order is not maintained.

Comment: This only is a good idea in very rare cases. Why so specific? This usually causes more problems than it solves.

Comment: This defines the nested elements serial and no other places will be impacted with the design.

Comment: I did not deny that. I only said it is typically not required and causes problems.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put commas between each class/id/element.

```
div, .form-group, .newFormRightContent {

}
.form-group, .newFormRightContent {

}

.newFormRightContent {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `.form-group div` has some style marked with `!important` in css.
Than you should try also to make your style important for your child div.
e.g

```
.newFormRightContent {
 background-color:#cecece!important;
}
```

Is this html code block inside IFrame ?

Comment: Ouch. That hurts. Why not find out what the problem is instead of throwing nuclear missiles at it?

Comment: .newFormRightContent or .form-group. newFormRightContent  is 100% correct what he used. He just wrote some specific style for the div .newFormRightContent. What else should you expect?